# PHP - rename files in temp folder

Tags: php, rename

I am trying to rename all files I have in my temporal upload folder and instead give the files a unique ID reference number as filename followed by `_x` suffix that is supposed to increase after each rename, resulting in file names such as `myidnumber_1.jpg, myidnumber_2.jpg, etc.`

Problem is, my code doesnt seem to like the rename command and also does not keep the file extension. Any suggestions on how to address this?

```
// Get array of all files in temp folder and rename
$check_folder = scandir("../../pages/fo_dmlog/attachments/".$_SESSION['Holidex']."/temp/".$_SESSION['myusername']."/");
$n = 1;

foreach ($check_folder as $check_file) {
    if (in_array($check_file, array(".",".."))) continue;

    $newName = str_replace($check_file,$logID."_".$n,$check_file);
    rename($check_folder . $check_file, $check_folder . $newName);

    echo "Attachment: $check_file<br>";
    $n++;
}
```

EDIT:

```
// Get array of all files in temp folder and rename
$check_folder = scandir("../../pages/fo_dmlog/attachments/".$_SESSION['Holidex']."/temp/".$_SESSION['myusername']."/");
$logID = "132456";
$n = 1;

foreach ($check_folder as $check_file) {
    if (in_array($check_file, array(".",".."))) continue;

    $extension = end(explode(".", $check_file));
    $newName = str_replace($check_file,$logID."_".$n.$extension,$check_file);
    rename($check_folder . $check_file, $check_folder . $newName);

    // instead of rename, can also move the files right away
    //move_uploaded_file($newName, "../".$logID."/" .$newName);

    echo "Attachment: $newName<br>";
    $n++;
}
```

Comment: 1. It's better to work with absolute files paths. 2. You're using the variable `$logID`which I don't see defined somewhere. 3. You are replacing the complete filename (which includes the extension) with the previously mysterious variable (`$logID`) + "_" and a number. You first need to save the file extension and then append it after renaming the file again.

Comment: Btw, you are renaming all the files every time this script is run?

Comment: 1. It doesn't make sense rename all files each time You run script, use move_uploaded_file after upload 2. If you want rename all files in some path I recommend use bash script to that, and call it from php

Comment: this is merely a snippet of the whole code, naturally I have additional code that handles the moving of the files and where the `$logID` is defined. So I basically have to implode() the filename for the extension, define the new filename, and rename as part of the moving of the files, is that right? Let me adjust, I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback, the following code works:

```
// Get array of all files in temp folder and rename
$dir = "../../pages/fo_dmlog/attachments/".$_SESSION['Holidex']."/temp/".$_SESSION['myusername']."/";
$check_folder = scandir($dir);
$n = 1;

foreach ($check_folder as $check_file) {
    if (in_array($check_file, array(".",".."))) continue;

    $extension = end(explode(".", $check_file));
    $newName = str_replace($check_file,$n.'.'.$extension,$check_file);
    rename($dir . $check_file, $dir . $newName);

    // instead of rename, can also move the files right away
    //move_uploaded_file($newName, "../".$log_ID."/" .$newName);

    echo "Attachment: $newName<br>";
    $n++;
}
```

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Cleaner way to get the extension: `$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I would imagine using a function designed for that purpose would be better than splitting (and thus creating a new array) and then fetch the last index. But as I said, I haven't done any benchmark on it. It would probably be micro-optimization, anyway.